# Change Machine Only Counting Quarters

Tags: java, if-statement, logic, currency

I'm having an issue with a change machine I'm building for my Java class. I'm very new to programming so this may be a dumb logic error. My change machine asks the user to input the price of the item then amount paid then it is supposed to calculate how much change the user will receive in quarters, dimes, etc... However, it's only counting 1 quarter each time. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    float penny = .1F, nickel = .5F, dime = .10F, quarter = .25F;
    int pennyCtr = 0, nickelCtr = 0, dimeCtr = 0, quarterCtr = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Purchase Price: ");
    float price = scan.nextFloat();
    DecimalFormat paidFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    System.out.println("Enter Amount Paid: ");
    float paid = scan.nextFloat();

    float change = (float) (paid - price);

    System.out.println("Your change from $" + paidFormat.format(paid) 
            + " is: " + change);

    if (change >= .25)
    {
        change -= quarter;
        quarterCtr++;
    }
    else if (change < .25)
    {
        change -= dime;
    dimeCtr++;
    }
    else if (change < .10)
    {
    change -= nickel;
    nickelCtr++;
    }
    else if (change < .5)
    {
        change -= penny;
        pennyCtr++;
    }

    System.out.println("Your change from $" + paidFormat.format(paid) +
            " is: " + quarterCtr + " Quarters, " + dimeCtr + " Dimes, "
            + nickelCtr + " Nickles, " + pennyCtr + " Pennies. ");

    System.out.println("Program written by Ashley ");
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be using some while loops up there?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Yes? While (change != 0) maybe? I'm really new to this. I'll try that but I'm not sure it'll solve the problem of it only counting one quarter.. **edit: It did help! thank you! now I just have to get it to stop continuously counting dimes..**

Comment: I bet it does; keep trying.

Comment: @AshleyTaylor: Hint: Look at the last else if statement and the float penny/nickel declaration. Are you sure they're right?

Comment: After that, you might want to look into [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for dealing with decimals.

Comment: @AshleyTaylor: You may also want to use paidFormat to output the change for the first time. Be aware that dealing with floats/doubles can be a little unusual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1):

Some general hints:

1. Look at how you are declaring your variables, especially penny and nickel.
2. Look at how you are calculating change. Is that right?
3. You need a `while` loop. How long should it loop for? When should the loop end?
4. When you print out "Your change from...", consider how you could output the change neatly.
5. Google some questions about float subtraction - it's not as easy as it first seems! Consider using `double` instead for your declarations and input.

Comment: 1+ for nudging her towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the code tells me that you are missing a loop between this block of code:

```
if (change >= .25)
{
    change -= quarter;
    quarterCtr++;
}
else if (change < .25)
{
    change -= dime;
dimeCtr++;
}
else if (change < .10)
{
change -= nickel;
nickelCtr++;
}
else if (change < .5)
{
    change -= penny;
    pennyCtr++;
}
```

Essentially, your program will terminate before it can reduce the change to 0. This is why you are only counting 1 coin every time. Consider maybe a while loop (while change > 0) perhaps.

Comment: I added a while loop at the start of my if statement..I'm still only counting 1 coin everytime though..while (change >= 0) { and then I start my if/else statements }

Comment: @AshleyTaylor: Have you had any more luck?

Comment: @AndrewMartin yes all of the comments have been really helpful. The while loop did the trick now I'm just looking into decimals. You're right, the penny/nickel were the wrong value. It should be 01 & 05 but I'm not sure I even need the decimal. The while loop is also causing it to print a line for each coin count but I think I can solve that.

Comment: @AshleyTaylor: I posted some hints. Your while loop only needs to run around the if and else statements